# How do I put php echo inside an html url?

Tags: php, html, facebook, variables

So i'd like to have the following:

```
example/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://example.com/blahblah
```

It is to change URL based on the page that its on so I used the below

```
example/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $share['reference_url'];?>">
```

When i do this i only see the following as the url

example/sharer/sharer.php?u=

So Question is how do i get both together? What is wrong with the below that is making the variable URL not show up. If i put it into a  alone by itself the reference_url shows up just fine

```
example/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $share['reference_url'];?>">
```

Comment: Are you sure `$share['reference_url']` actually has a value? I bet it doesn't.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *"If i put it into a alone by itself the reference_url shows up just fine"*?

Comment: please check $share['reference_url'] has a value ?